# Contact Database Relationships

Tags: java, mysql, relationship

I hope everybody is fine and healthy.

I am creating contacts table for my database and come across some thought to check the relationship of tables in Mysql than i will code it JAVA.

Let me explain what i am trying to do is i have (Users, Employees, Vendors, Customers, (Owners this will be created later on)) this is for now, and each one have their table of information in it and a link to ContactDetails table to see their contact details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05h4P.png)

Firstly i want you to comment if any design of fields have issue in below.

Secondly the relationship i have created is correct.

Many thanks for your kind help and support.

Comment: Instead of having Business and Personal details table separately, you can just get them in the same table with another column (bit/boolean) to declare if it's a business or personal row.

Comment: Everything looks good. I like Martheen's suggestion of creating a singular Details table.

Comment: May be it's better to change the name of foreign keys ContactID to ContactDetailID

Answer (score 0):

A lot to think about here. You could get rid of tables `Users`, `Employees`, `Vendors` and `Customers`. And there's no need to create additional ones like `Owners`. You already have the type of customer/person/organization/entity in the `ContactTypes` table. If you need a table like `ContactDetailsInfo` to replace those tables I'm pretty sure you can manage with a single table and link that to `ContactDetails.Id`.

Continuing in the spirit of normalization you could create three or four tables instead of `BusinessDetails` and `PersonalDetails`:

1. `Addresses`
2. `Phones`
3. `Emails`
4. `HomePage`

These link directly to the `ContactDetails.Id` so you'll get an unlimited amount of contact information per type for each `ContactDetails.Id`. *Unlimited* is of course an exaggeration and unpractical but just define some types for each address, phone number and email, like personal/home, office, office2, business etc. This way you'll never end up in a situation where you store (many) empty columns in the database. (Think of a person who has only one email address or telephone number stored in the database.)

I don't see a need for the `Country` and `City` tables. These should already be present in the address information. `Country` might be a useful lookup table i.e. for international shipping information (and then it should be removed from the address information). But unless you want to keep track of every freaking city in the world, I would not make a dedicated table to them. Just think of how many cities are there in the world...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you like to keep Customer, Vendor and the other because you have additional information to store in each of these types.

One ContactDetail represents a set of contact information items related to a single person. As ZZ-bb already proposed I also think it is better to have separated tables for the different media types. Because the cardinality of each media type can be different.

I don't understand the relationship `Customer -1---M- ContactDetails` as one ContactDetail already represents multiple types of information. I would invert the relation: Customer, Vendor, Employees, Others each have a contactDetailsId. This way you can even get rid of the ContactType table except if you want to query ContactDetails without linking to the Customers, Vendors,... but still want to filter on this type.

In your ContactDetail implementation I assume every record will only have a value in one of the fields CustomerId, VendorId, EmployeeId.

In theory you can link the same ContactDetails to Vendors and Customers (in case the person is a vendor and a customer) but I don't think this is a good idea as its contact information may be different depending on the role.

So my proposition:

```
Vendors    -1------------1-ContactDetails  -1---------M-- Email
 -contactDetailsId    //  /  -contactDetailsId      \       -contactDetailsId
                     //  /   -(contacttype)          \--M- Address
Customers ----------//  /                             \     -contactDetailsId
 -contactDetailsId  /  /                               \-M- Phone
                   /  /                                      -contactDetailsId
Employees --------/  /
 -contactDetailsId  /
                   /
Others -----------/
 -contactDetailsId
```